# Xamarin.Forms - Screen black when using NavigationPage

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms

I am adding a `NavigationPage` in a Xamarin.Forms app. After adding the `NavigationPage`, the screen was black and not showing the target page.

This is a new project, so the code is quite simple.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HostingPage());
    }
```

The `HostingPage` is a `ContentPage` with a `Label`, `Entry` and `Button`. I expected to see the `HostingPage`, but end up seeing a black screen.

In the `MainActivity` of the Android project, it was extending like this by default:

```
[Activity(Label = "Meeting.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        LoadApplication(new App());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `Theme = "@style/MyTheme"` from `MainActivity` of Android Project

Answer (score 0):

Replace **global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity** by **Activity** and remove **Theme = "@style/MyTheme"** from attribute of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HostingPage());
    }
}
```

Your must make do this way:

```
MainPage = new new HostingPage();
```